# MySQL select from table 2 same as table 1

Tags: mysql, join, request, cross-join

I have two tables

**"employers":**

```
  emp_id  empl_name     wage
    1     john          20/h
    2     mike          20/h
    3     sam           30/h
```

**"positions":**

```
  pos_id  emp_id  pos_name   related_pos
    1      1      cleaner       0
    2      3      driver        3
    3      2      bodyguard     0
```

I need display table with
Employer Name, Position Name, Wage, Related Position Name, Rel Pos Wage, Rel Pos Employer

Now i have query:

```
SELECT pos_name, empl_name, wage 
   FROM positions
      LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.emp_id = positions.emp_id
```

next rquest does not work, but gives idea of what i need:

```
SELECT pos_name, empl_name, wage, (SELECT empl_name
                                      FROM positions 
                                         LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.emp_id = positions.related_pos) as emp2,
                                  (SELECT pos_name 
                                      FROM positions
                                         WHERE pos_id = related_pos) as pos2
   FROM positions
      LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.emp_id = positions.emp_id
```

Comment: Does not give the idea to me. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Humm.. a query that isnt giving what you need isnt really way to describe the problem. Can you just put the output of the query you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do the work.

```
SELECT 
p.pos_name, 
p.empl_name, 
p.wage, 
(SELECT pos_name FROM positions WHERE pos_id = p.related_pos) as pos2
FROM positions as p
INNER JOIN employers as e ON e.emp_id = p.emp_id
```

I removed the following code.

```
 (SELECT empl_name FROM positions 
  LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.emp_id = positions.related_pos) as emp2,
```

Because I think there are two errors. First there is no `empl_name` column in the table. Second this Subquery will give more then on result for a row.
This also applies for the fist Subquery, when there is more then one entry for a `emp_id`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've just made this more complicated than it needs to be.  You're looking to link tables, if I understand correctly.  Break this down into three parts:

Your SELECT should include Employer Name, Position Name, Wage, Related Position Name, Rel Pos Wage, Rel Pos Employer

FROM employers, positions

WHERE positions.emp_id = employers.emp_id

This will get you a list of all the items from employers as they pair up with positions.

Sorry if this isn't what you meant.  Give me a nod if it is.